# Creating multiple object in other class C++

Tags: c++, arrays, object, inheritance

I made hospital class and patient class, so what I am trying to do is to make Patient[] patients < this. However, there is showing some error error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
I do not know what it is wrong with that. 
Thank you for your response.

```
class Hospital
{
    public:
        Hospital();
        void determinePatientType();


    protected:

    private:
        Patient[] patients;
        char * fileName;
        int patientCapacity;
        char * hospitalName;
        int totalPatients;
};
```

Comment: Do some research about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). And of course read [a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) as that syntax is wrong.

Comment: You cannot create an array without a size. Try `std::vector<Patient>` instead.

Comment: Does the Hospital class include the patient header file?

Comment: what if I want to use dynamic allocation ?.. Where can I assign the size of array of that object? Thanks.

Comment: @Alan Yes I included header file of patient.

Comment: Havent actually built this, but I think replacing the array of patients with Vector<Patient> patients; Should do it? Also include the vecotr type

Comment: The correct syntax would be `Patient patients[10];`, but better use `std::vector<Patient> patients;` as @Someprogrammerdude already suggested. Same goes for `fileName` and `hospitalName`, work with [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1- That is not how to declare an array:

```
    Patient[] patients;
```

You must make the subscript operator after the identifier not before it.

```
    Patient patients[size];
```

2- You have to specify array size at compile time so:

```
patient pat[size];
```

The size must be constant at compile time. If you want a dynamic size then consider using dynamic arrays. Also i recommend using class vector.

To use a dynamic array you should use pointesrs:

```
patient* patients;
```

And layer on you can allocate it:

```
patients = new patient[size];
```

Your class could look like:

nclude 
using namespace std;

```
class Hospital{
       public:
        Hospital(int); // constructor
        ~Hospital(); // destructor
        Hospital();
        void determinePatientType();

    private:
        Patient* patients;
        char * fileName;
        int patientCapacity;
        char * hospitalName;
        int totalPatients;
};

Hospital::Hospital(int size){
    patients = new Patient[size]; // allocating dynamic memory
    // some initialization and processing here

}

Hospital::~Hospital(){
    delete[] patients; //freeing up memory
}
```

Comment: Could you let me know how to use dynamic array over there in case of mine?

Comment: Oh thanks, lastly, I have a quick question for that, it has to be in main function? or which part has to include that syntax?

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance. Right now I got it.

Comment: Your pointer solution violates the Rule of Five, which will create undefined behaviour and/or memory leaks whenever someone copies or moves a `Hospital`. There is no reason not to use `std::vector` here.

Comment: I don't provide a full example i just answered the question of the OP.